# Can you format the style of the DropDownList in yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

Can you format the style of the DropDownList in yii2 I have the following code that generates a list from a table and I wanted to change the text size and color of the items to choose from.

```
    <div class="form-group search-form">
    <?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'spec')
    ->dropDownList(
        $specialities,    
        ['prompt'=>'Any Speciality']
    )->label('');
    ?>
    </div><!--end of form-group-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should  be the  options

```
<div class="form-group search-form">
<?php 
      echo $form->field($model, 'spec')
      ->dropDownList(
            $specialities,    
            ['prompt'=>'Any Speciality', 
            'options' => ['style' => 'color: #FA4577; font-size: 18px;'],]
       )->label('');
?>
</div><!--end of form-group-->
```

Comment: It's not working for me - of course it doesn't mean that this is not the right answer.

Comment: For me it's working this way: `['prompt' => Yii::t('yii', 'Select'), 'style' => 'color: red; font-size: 18px;',]` so without `options`.

Comment: @user2511599  .  you should post a new question with your code  .. and describe your need  and your specific problems ... eventually comment me the link

Comment: you code is not enough .. or if you thinks of have found a valid solution  you can add  your code as a new answer ..

Comment: `<?=
            $form->field($model, 'zwzx_id')->dropDownList(
                ZwzX::find()->getBiggerActiveAsArray($a->fn, $a->zn, $a->z, $a->drz, $a->p), [
                    'prompt' => Yii::t('yii', 'Select'),
                    'style' => 'color: red; font-size: 18px;',
            ]);
            ?>` I think it's basically quite the same.

Comment: I don't think my answer is better, I just have no clue why it's not working for me, when it was obviously working for @samauto Changes in framework maybe...?

Comment: take a look at ref for check  ..  (seems correct to me) anyway seem there are some change with yii 2.0.11 ..   https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeDropDownList()-detail

Comment: Yeah, seems correct. Pretty strange. However, sometimes documentation is also not 100% perfect.

Comment: in the code i'm  use i have some of this object and works  correcly .. .

Comment: I have Yii 2.0.15.1 what do you have?

Comment: @user2511599   actually i'm on 2.0.14.1

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference, but I have no clue